# Parse of HTTP response to JSON data

Tags: python, json, http

sorry for the noob question, but need help on parsing of HTTP response which i receive after post request.

There is example :

```
import requests
import json
import base64
url = 'someURL'
if __name__=='__main__':
    data = '{"requests":"data"}'
    r = requests.post(url, data)
    print(r.content)
    print(r.encoding)
```

I'm receiving the next :

> b'{"results":[{"hits":[{"aliases":["Defence of the Ancients
>   2","Defense of the Ancients 2","\xe0\xbc\xbc \xe3\x81\xa4
>   \xe2\x97\x95_\xe2\x97\x95
>   \xe0\xbc\xbd\xe3\x81\xa4"],"localizations":{},"name":"Dota
>   2","popularity":36184,"objectID":"29595","*highlightResult":{"aliases":[{"value":"Defence
>   of the Ancients
>   2","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]},{"value":"Defense of the
>   Ancients
>   2","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]},{"value":"\xe0\xbc\xbc
>   \xe3\x81\xa4 \xe2\x97\x95*\xe2\x97\x95
>   \xe0\xbc\xbd\xe3\x81\xa4","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]}],"name":{"value":"*Dota*
>   2","matchLevel":"full","fullyHighlighted":false,"matchedWords":["dota"]}}},{"aliases":["Blizzard
>   All-Stars","Blizzard DOTA","HOTS"],"localizations":{},"name":"Heroes
>   of the
>   Storm","popularity":27143,"objectID":"32959","_highlightResult":{"aliases":[{"value":"Blizzard
>   All-Stars","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]},{"value":"Blizzard
>   *DOTA*","matchLevel":"full","fullyHighlighted":false,"matchedWords":["dota"]},{"value":"HOTS","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]}],"name":{"value":"Heroes
>   of the
>   Storm","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]}}},{"aliases":[],"localizations":{},"name":"Fujiko
>   F. Fujio Characters Daishuugou! SF Dotabata
>   Party!!","popularity":0,"objectID":"490150","_highlightResult":{"name":{"value":"Fujiko
>   F. Fujio Characters Daishuugou! SF *Dota*bata
>   Party!!","matchLevel":"full","fullyHighlighted":false,"matchedWords":["dota"]}}},{"aliases":[],"localizations":{},"name":"\xe5\x88\x80\xe5\xa1\x94\xe5\x82\xb3\xe5\xa5\x87
>   Dota
>   Legend","popularity":0,"objectID":"488497","_highlightResult":{"name":{"value":"\xe5\x88\x80\xe5\xa1\x94\xe5\x82\xb3\xe5\xa5\x87
>   *Dota*
>   Legend","matchLevel":"full","fullyHighlighted":false,"matchedWords":["dota"]}}}],"nbHits":4,"page":0,"nbPages":1,"hitsPerPage":1000,"processingTimeMS":1,"facets":{},"exhaustiveFacetsCount":true,"exhaustiveNbHits":true,"query":"dota","params":"query=dota&page=0&hitsPerPage=99999&numericFilters=%5B%5D&facets=*&facetFilters=","index":"game"}]}\n'
>
> UTF-8

But how i can try to encode, format it still have a different issues. Please help, how this reqeust get to valid json?

there is my BAD examples :

```
print(j.json())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_games.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(r.json())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0f3c' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)
```

or this :

```
json.loads(str(r.content)[1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_games.py", line 17, in <module>
    a = json.loads(str(r.content)[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: You should never ever try to convert bytes to string by taking the `str` of it and then cutting the `b` off the beginning. For one thing, you still have the `'` at the end. More importantly, instead of actually decoding the bytes, you're decoding the backslash-escaped representation of those bytes, which is useless. If you want to turn `bytes` in a particular encoding into `str`, just call `decode` on it.

Comment: In other words: `r.content.decode(r.encoding)`. But this should give you the same thing as `r.text`, so there's not much point. Plus. `r.json` should already do this for you; your problem appears to be that you're calling it on some other thing `j`, which has presumably wrapped things up in some way that prevents you from using the encoding on the page and therefore defaults to ASCII.

Comment: Finally, since this is UTF-8, you should be able to just load the encoded bytes with `json.loads(r.content)` without even attempting to decode it.

Comment: unfortuntaely any from these variants are not valid :( i also tried these ones, but all the time have codding error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0f3c' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Well, you don't get that error from the example you gave in your question, and it's hard to imagine how you could, unless you were trying to decode from ASCII rather than UTF-8. So, you need to show us a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your error.

Answer (score 0):

Something is strange in your report, because printing `j.json()` results in a error with `r.json()` in it....

Your second attempt would work, if you didn't use `str()` to do implicit decoding.

Try the explicit, fully verbose way:

```
print(json.loads(r.content.decode(r.encoding)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately still have an issue with decoding "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0f3c' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: That issue is not a decode error, since it is a `UnicodeEncodeError` so it is an error encoding, not decoding. Try doing both separately, first do `obj = json.loads(r.content.decode(r.encoding))` and in the line below do `print(obj)` ... if the error is in the `print` part, the decoding is working.